# Why Android says that I am using a lot of storage in pictures and videos?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, internal-storage, images, huawei

If I see the Internal Storage, it says that I am using 4.7 GB in "Pictures, videos". However, when I do click in it, I see the gallery, where in total I am using 93.98 MB!!

How is this possible? What is wrong? How to fix it and get more free space?

My phone is a HUAWEI P6-U06 with Android 4.2.2

Comment: Look into those folders with a file manager, it's possible that the `cache` folder contains some large cache files. Make sure you made invisible folders visible (those beginning with a `.` for instance).

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pictures and videos are hidden from the gallery.

Install "[Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander)" or another app to search on entire disk for files `*.jpg`, `*.avi`, `*.mp4`, etc.

Ensure you delete WhatsApp photos and videos.